# React Native code on launch crashing application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, reactjs, react-native

I am getting below message when crashing.

> `RCTTVNavigationEventEmitter` requires main queue setup since it overrides
>   `init` but doesn't implement `requiresMainQueueSetup`. In a future release
>   React Native will default to initializing all native modules on a
>   background thread unless explicitly opted-out of.

Code :

```
NSString *bearerToken = REQUESTS.oAuthRequest.accessToken;
NSURL *jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"home.ios" fallbackResource:nil];

RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation moduleProvider:nil launchOptions:nil];
NSDictionary *props = @{@"bearer_token" : bearerToken, @"area_id":SELECTED_AREA_ID};
rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge moduleName:@"Order" initialProperties:props];
rootView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 64, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT - 112);
[self.view addSubview:rootView];
```

Comment: Your question has too little information. Please add more details. For example, are you using Expo? When did this error start occuring (added a new module, from first run, etc.)? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nil I found in the props due to that I was getting this error.

```
NSDictionary *props = @{@"bearer_token" : bearerToken ? bearerToken : @"bearer_token", @"area_id":SELECTED_AREA_ID};
```